# how to achieve "product of two monads" effect?

Tags: haskell, monads

Suppose we have two monads, `m` and `m'`. Now, suppose we have variables,

```
-- in real problems, the restriction is some subclass MyMonad, so don't worry
-- if it's the case here that mx and f must essentially be pure.
mx :: Monad m'' => m'' a
f :: Monad m'' => a -> m'' b
```

Is there a way to create anything similar to the product `m x m'`? I know this is possible with Arrows, but it seems more complicated (impossible?) for monads, especially when trying to write what `mx >>= f` should do.

To see this, define

```
data ProdM a = ProdM (m a) (m' a)
instance Monad ProdM where
    return x = ProdM (return x) (return x)
```

but now, when we define `mx >>= f`, it's not clear which value from `mx` to pass to `f`,

```
    (ProdM mx mx') >>= f
        {- result 1 -} = mx >>= f
        {- result 2 -} = mx' >>= f
```

I want `(mx >>= f) :: ProdM` to be isomorphic to `((mx >>= f) :: m) x ((mx >>= f) :: m')`.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, this type is a monad. The key is simply to pass *both* results to `f`, and only keep the matching field from the result. That is, we keep the first element from the result of passing `mx`'s result, and the second element from the result of passing `mx'`'s result. The instance looks like this:

```
instance (Monad m, Monad m') => Monad (ProdM m m') where
  return a = ProdM (return a) (return a)
  ProdM mx mx' >>= f = ProdM (mx >>= fstProd . f) (mx' >>= sndProd . f)
    where fstProd (ProdM my _) = my
          sndProd (ProdM _ my') = my'
```

`ProdM` is available in the [monad-products](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-products) package under the name `Product`.

Comment: The solution of ehird also means, that the action f is run twice. This might be unexpected if the monads m and m' have observable side-effects.